# check 2d array diagonally?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to search a 3x3 2d array diagonally, like this:[image]

I want to check if all boxes in the diagonal have the same value. Here is how I try to do it:

```
thisOne = board[0][2];    //set to 'X'
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j = 3; j>0; j--){
            if(board[i][j-1] != thisOne) {
                thisOne= '\0';
            }
        }
    }
//since all boxes were 'X', thisOne is still set to 'X'
if(thisOne != '\0') {
    winner = thisOne;
    printf("vinnare på nördöst\n");
}
```

So after running this code, `winner` should be 'X', if all boxes are X's. But the code does not do that, why is that?

Comment: `for(i = 0, j = 3-1; i < 3; i++, j--) { if(board[i][j] != thisOne) { thisOne = '\0'; break; } }`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY oh I see now why it did not work. Thanks! You can answer the questions if you want me to accept&upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check only diagonal cells instead of checking all the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You are not breaking/exiting the check loop when the first not matching char is retrieved.

Moreover your nested for does not what you guess: inner one loops into all columns of each row, but you want to che only the diagonal values...

You can easily a simple `while`

```
int i=0;
int j=2;
while ((i<3) && (j>=0) && (board[i][j] == thisOne))
{
   i++;
   j--;
}

// if i<3 the diagonal is not full of thisOne char
if ( i < 3)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by @BLUEPIXY, the problem is that the `j` loop is nested inside the `i` loop. So for every iteration in the `i` loop, the `j` loop runs 3 times on every column, instead of just working on the minor diagonal. There are several ways to fix this, although the most optimal way would be to use only one single loop and only one variable `i`.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if(board[i][2-i]!=thisOne) {
        thisOne='\0'
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you'd simply need to decrement X iterator & Y iterator when going through your array.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void)
{
  int   arr[3][3];
  int   it_y;
  int   it_x;

  it_y = 0;
  it_x = 2;
  arr[0][0] = 0;
  arr[0][1] = 1;
  arr[0][2] = 2;
  arr[1][0] = 3;
  arr[1][1] = 4;
  arr[1][2] = 5;
  arr[2][0] = 6;
  arr[2][1] = 7;
  arr[2][2] = 8;
  while (it_x < 3 && it_x >= 0)
    {
      printf("[%d][%d]: '%d'\n", it_y, it_x, arr[it_y][it_x]);
      --it_x;
      ++it_y;
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
for(int row=0,col=2; row<3; row++,col--)
{
    if(board[row][col] != thisOne) 
    {
            thisOne= '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: print the I,j values you will get the required diagonal indexes 0,2 ; 1,1; 2,0

Answer (score 0):

You can only check diagonal elements like this

```
for(i = 0, j = 3-1; i < 3; i++, j--) { 
    if(board[i][j] != thisOne) { 
       thisOne = '\0'; 
    } 
 }
```